# Is there a way to turn off the file autosave feature in PAW?

Tags: paw-app

Sorry for such a simple question, but I don't see any way to NOT save a file update in Paw.
When troubleshooting, I often open up a paw file to retrieve a request that was working earlier. I usually try the request a few different ways before figuring out the problem. 
Then when I'm ready to leave Paw, I want to close Paw WITHOUT saving the file.

But by that time, Paw has already silently saved the file and my original (working!) request has been overwritten with my troubleshooting junk.

So how can I go in and muck about with a request without saving it?
Hopefully I'm just missing something really simple.

Answer (score 5):

There's no option to disable the autosave that I've found.

Paw stores all of your previous requests so it's easy to find and restore your last successful request even if you've closed the file and re-opened it.

While in split view, on the response pane you can click the clock icon to view your request history, find your last successful request, then copy and paste the contents to the request pane.

You can also cycle through old requests by hitting ⌘ + [